# Am I interpreting C order of operations correctly here?

Tags: c, language-lawyer, order-of-execution, sequence-points

I was puzzled by the fact that [CPPReference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/eval_order) says that postincrement’s value evaluation is sequenced before its side-effect, but preincrement has no such guarantee.

I have now come up with an example where this matters but I am unsure if my analysis is correct.

As I understand it, these two programs differ in that the first contains UB, and the second does not:

```c
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int arr[] = {0, 1, 2};
    int i = 1;
    int x = ++arr[arr[i]];
}
```

```c
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int arr[] = {0, 1, 2};
    int i = 1;
    int x = arr[arr[i]]++;
}
```

My analysis of the expression `++arr[arr[i]]` is as follows:

1. There are these *sequenced-before* relations:

   - Value computation of `i` is sequenced before value computation of `arr[i]`
   - Value computation of `arr[i]` is sequenced before value computation of `arr[arr[i]]`
   - Value computation of `arr[arr[i]]` is sequenced before value computation of `++arr[arr[i]]`
2. The side-effect of `++arr[arr[i]]` is unsequenced with respect to these.
3. The compiler may choose any order satisfying these relations and may delete the value computation of `arr[arr[i]]` since it is not used.
4. In any possible ordering, the value computation of `arr[arr[i]]` refers to the same scalar object as `arr[i]`.
5. The side effect of `++arr[arr[i]]` modifies the scalar object `arr[arr[i]]`, but it is accessed unsequenced to that by `arr[i]`.

However, if we use postincrement instead, we introduce a new *sequenced-before* relation: The value computation of `arr[arr[i]]++` is sequenced before its side-effect. Therefore, by transitivity, the side-effect is no longer unsequenced to `arr[i]`.

However, I am unsure if this is accurate. In particular, I am not sure how exactly evaluation of post-/preincrement is defined. Does it perform a value computation of its operand? If it does, does this mean that `++*ptr` is UB while `(*ptr)++` is not? If it does not, how is the value computation of the full expression performed—can any operator access the value of an lvalue expression without performing value computation on that expression?

Comment: I don't see how the value computation of `arr[arr[i]]` can be "deleted" as you say, since you necessarily need it to calculate `++arr[arr[i]]`. Also, the CPPreference page you link states *"The value computation of the postincrement and postdecrement operators is sequenced before its side-effect."* under C11 (which I guess is where you read about this?). The only difference between pre- and post-increment/decrement is that the former evaluates to the new value while the latter evaluates to the old value. The old value computation necessarily needs to happen before the operation is applied.

Comment: But there is no statement about preincrement/-decrement’s sequencing. While it necessarily must happen in sequence it is not sequenced, so goes my interpretation.

Comment: It also seems to me that deleting the `arr[arr[i]]` is immaterial to whether `++arr[arr[i]]` is sequenced with respect to `arr[i]`

Comment: …that’s the question. It’s exactly about this sentence. Am I interpreting it correctly to imply that the above expressions are with UB and w/o UB, respectively?

Comment: Sorry, I misread that quote.

Comment: It is nothing about `language-lawyer` here

Comment: I don't think the `sequence points` tag is appropriate here, as this is about sequencing, not sequence points.

Comment: It appears that the C standard (draft) specifies: “The expression ++E is equivalent to (E+=1) […]”, N3096, 6.5.3.1 Prefix increment and decrement operators, which invalidates part of my analysis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The analysis is incorrect. In particular, it is not the case that the side-effect of `++arr[arr[i]]` is unsequenced to the other value computations. This is because the C standard (**Note**: I have only read a draft of the C standard, [N3096](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n3096.pdf)) specifies that `++E` is equivalent to `E += 1`:

> [6.5.16]
> The expression ++E is equivalent to (E+=1), where the value 1
> is of the appropriate type.

Further, it specifies that assignment operators incl. augmented assignment operators have their constituent expressions’ value computations sequenced before their side effect:

> [6.5.3.1]
> The side effect of updating the stored value of the left operand is sequenced after the value computations of the left and right operands.

Answer (score 3):

The expressions

```
arr[arr[i]]++;
```

and

```
++arr[arr[i]];
```

are both correct. There is neither undefined behavior.

The subscript operator is defined like

```
postfix-expression [ expression ]
```

So the above expressions may be rewritten like

```
arr[some-expression]++
```

and

```
++arr[some-expression]
```

where some-expression is `arr[i]`.

The subscript operator `arr[i]` is defined like `*( arr + i )` where the array designator is implicitly converted to a pointer to its first element of type `int *`. The evaluated expression yields lvalue of the i-th element of the array value of which is used in the original subscript operator

```
arr[some-expression]
```

and then is evaluated like

```
*( arr + value-of-some-expression )
```

that again yields lvalue of the array element of the index value-of-some-expression.

The result of the postfix increment operator is the lvalue of its operand. As a side effect the value of the operand is incremented.

The value of the unary increment operator is the value of its ioerand after its increment.

Pay attention to that postfix operators have higher precedence than unary operators and are evaluated from left to right while unary operators are evaluated from right to left.

Relative to your code you have that the variable `x` gets the value of the second element of the array that is equal to `1` and as a result of the side effect the value of the second element will be incremented and become equal to `2` due to the postfix subscript operator.

If there is used the unary subscript operator then the variable `x` will get the value `2` .

As for your statements

> Value computation of i is sequenced before value computation of arr[i]

then (the C17 Standard, 6.5 Expressions_

> 1 An expression is a sequence of operators and operands that specifies
> computation of a value,86) or that designates an object or a function,
> or that generates side effects, or that performs a combination
> thereof. **The value computations of the operands of an operator are
> sequenced before the value computation of the result of the
> operator.**

And )6.5.2.4 Postfix increment and decrement operators)

> 2 **The result of the postfix++ operator is the value of the operand.
> As a side effect, the value of the operand object is incremented (that
> is, the value 1 of the appropriate type is added to it).** See the
> discussions of additive operators and compound assignment for
> information on constraints, types, and conversions and the effects of
> operations on pointers. The value computation of the result is
> sequenced before the side effect of updating the stored value of the
> operand. With respect to an indeterminately-sequenced function call,
> the operation of postfix++ is a single evaluation. Postfix ++ on an
> object with atomic type is a read-modify-write operation with
> memory_order_seq_cst memory order semantics.

And (6.5.3.1 Prefix increment and decrement operators_

> 2 **The value of the operand of the prefix++ operator is incremented.
> The result is the new value of the operand after incrementation.** The
> expression++E is equivalent to (E+=1). See the discussions of additive
> operators and compound assignment for information on constraints,
> types, side effects, and conversions and the effects of operations on
> pointers.

As for undefined behavior then

> 2 **If a side effect on a scalar object is unsequenced relative to
> either a different side effect on the same scalar object or a value
> computation using the value of the same scalar object, the behavior is
> undefined.** If there are multiple allowable orderings of the
> subexpressions of an expression, the behavior is undefined if such an
> unsequenced side effect occurs in any of the orderings.

and in the provided programs there is no such a situation. The first program could have undefined behavior if you wrote for example

```
int x = arr[arr[i]]++ + arr[arr[i]];
```

In this case the side effect of the expression `arr[arr[i]]++` is  unsequenced relative to the value computation of the expression `arr[arr[i]]`.

Here are some simple examples of undefined behavior

```
x = y + y++;
x = y + ++y;
x = y++ + ++y;
```

Comment: You wrote a lot about the postfix increment operation, but the OP seems almost exclusively confused by their misunderstanding of prefix increment (thinking it isn't sequenced in a way that postfix increment is).

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I think that It is clear from the quote for the postfix increment operator.